# Programmatically create order in shopware plugin

Tags: shopware

I need to create ShopWare 6 plugin that creates new orders from products that are received via AJAX POST request. I don't know how to do that. I googled and checked documentation but I couldn't find any info on how can it be done.

Does someone know how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best solution would be to create Cart object from products that you get from request probably you know context token so you can use the current customer's cart and add products to it, but also you can create a new cart and then call `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\OrderPersister::persist()` method to persist order from your cart.

Take a look here how to load/create a Cart
`\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\SalesChannel\CartLoadRoute::load()`